# MIN() aggregate function in SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

What is the logic behind MIN() aggregate function to evaluate data-types like 'CHAR' or 'VARCHAR2' ?

Comment: Please Accept the answer which explains your desired question.

Comment: Often the min() on a char / varchar is an arbitary aggregate on the value in a statement with a group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Min( VarcharType )` will return the lowest string value for that column in the result set, given the sorting order of the column in question.

Comment: How this string value is decided ? Let's take a practical example, if we were to find MIN() out of 'Curt' and 'Burt' ? How string value is determined of these two words ? or the string values are set according to the alphabetical order e.g. a<b<c<d<e<f<g....<z . Is it so ?

Comment: @RubbalBhusri  "Burt".    If you were to sort all the values of that column using the collation order active for that column, MIN() would return the first value, and MAX() would return the last value.

Comment: I think u said just the opposite, I just now tried on my Oracle DBMS, MIN() returns the last value of the column and MAX() returns the first value of the column. But anyways, your answer helped me in noticing the difference.

Comment: @RubbalBhusri If `MAX()` returned the (alphabetically) first result, then that column was sorted in descending order:   take a look at the underlying indices to confirm that that is the case.   What I said is true for columns sorted in "natural" (i.e. ascending) order.

Comment: `SELECT name FROM Animal ORDER BY name` will return `'Aardvark', 'Bear', 'Gorilla', 'Zebra'`.    On the other hand, `SELECT name FROM Animal ORDER BY name DESC` will return `'Zebra', 'Gorilla', 'Bear', 'Aardvark'`    `MIN(name)` will return `'Aardvark'`.   `MAX(name)` will return `'Zebra'`.

Comment: and if the values in column are present in the order as : 'Zebra','Aardvark','gorilla','bear' , then What logic will MiN() and MAX() applies ?

Comment: and if the values in column are present in the order as : 'Zebra','Aardvark','gorilla','bear' , then What logic will MiN() and MAX() applies ?  I mean, Does the existing order of values present in column matters or not ? or MIN() always give words starting with 'A' and MAX() always give words starting with 'Z', if they have to choose from two words starting with 'A' and 'Z' respectively.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34869/discussion-between-curt-and-rubbal-bhusri)

Answer (score 0):

Also MIN() returns the shortest string (in terms of length) but it's **alphabetically ordered.**

eg- There are two fruits :
1. Apple,
2. Kiwi.
Output:
Apple (because A comes before K although Kiwi is shorter than Apple).